# How to add search bar in navigation bar

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to implement the search bar in navigation bar for android in xamarin.forms,while searching i found many examples for ios but not for android.How to achieve this for android through customrenderer?

Comment: Try this: http://blog.xhackers.co/xamarin-forms-contentpage-with-searchbar-in-the-navigation-bar/ It is Android Custom Renderer example.

Comment: Thank you for replay,i will try that.

Comment: I am trying above link but I am not able to get search bar in nougat and above versions.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way to create a Search is to create class and make use of Filter options
like this

**Search Bar Button on Top**

```
 <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
            android:title="Search"
            app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
            app:showAsAction="always" />
```

**Classes You  May Require**

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

        return true;
    }

    //getting text from user
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        activity.getFilter().filter(newText);
        return false;
    }

    //submitting Text 
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String newText) {
        activity.getFilter().filter(newText);
        return false;
    }
```

This is other Activity

```
public Filter getFilter() {
        return filter;
    }
    private Filter filter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            List<Pokemon> to_be_filtered = new ArrayList<>();
            String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

            //implement search
           
            if(filterPattern.isEmpty())  {
                 to_be_filtered.addAll(fulllist);
            }
            else {
                for (some this iterate over ) {
                    if (get_name_of_required 
                         search.getName().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                        add_created_database_to_be_filtered.add(name of list variable);
                    }
                }
            }
```

In this you have to use inbuilt function called getfilter() it will handle Search bar.
Here I had used statements like to_be_filtered and add_created_database, You have to modify code according to database you are using.

I my case I  am having 2 activities in which the first three class i.e. OnQuerySearch... , Submit text and Save text are in MainActivity  and getFilter() is in another Activity

Thanks I hope you got your answer